# IOS Webkit to track the url which use is clicked and URL Scheme

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, wkwebview

Am trying to migrate my iOS UIWebview to Webkit, but along the line I ran into lot of problems. I have a code in `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` before which I used to monitor `urls and url-scheem` like `tell:, exit:, refresh:, mailto:` and to make sure that only my url can open in the WebView. But trying to implement that same way using webkit it didn't work please am not sure if am doing it in the write method can anyone help me.

/*Trying to implement it with webkit*/

```
- (BOOL)webView:(WKWebView *)inWeb decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType{
    NSLog(@"Event: %@", @"shouldStartLoadWithRequest inType called");
    NSArray *schemeArray = @[@"share", @"map", @"rate", @"reload", @"exit"];
    NSString *url = [[inRequest URL] query];
    NSString *scheme = [[inRequest URL] scheme];
    NSString *StrPurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url];

    NSLog(@"[inRequest URL] == %@", StrPurl);
    NSLog(@"[inRequest NSURL] == %@", url);
    NSLog(@"[[inRequest URL] scheme] == %@", scheme);

    if ([StrPurl containsString:@"mysite.com"]){
        //coninue open
    }else if ( [schemeArray containsObject:[[inRequest URL] scheme]] ){
        //open share intent
        NSLog(@"Event: Share URL %@", [[inRequest URL] scheme]);
    }

    NSLog(@"Event: Request URL %@", url);
    return NO;
}
```

Using the above example in UIWebview it work

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType{

    if (self.validatedRequest || inType != UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked){
        NSString *url = [[inRequest URL] query];
        NSString *scheme = [[inRequest URL] scheme];
        NSString *StrPurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url];

        NSLog(@"[inRequest URL] == %@", StrPurl);
        NSLog(@"[inRequest NSURL] == %@", url);
        NSLog(@"[[inRequest URL] scheme] == %@", scheme);
    }
}
```

Also I have this method but it doesn't get called when I click on tel: or other external url

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler {
    NSLog(@"Event: %@", @"shouldStartLoadWithRequest navigationType called");
        //if (navigationAction.navigationType == WKNavigationTypeLinkActivated) {
        if (navigationAction.navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {

        }
    NSString *url = [navigationAction.request.URL query];
    NSLog(@"Event: Request URL %@", url);
    decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this delegate method:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView 
    decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction 
    decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler;
```

Instead of returning `NO` you will need to call either `decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyAllow)` or `decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicyCancel)`

You can access the `NSURLRequest` using `navigationAction.request`.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455641-webview?language=objc

Comment: Please can you give me the full code am trying but too many errors

Comment: I already have a method like this before but it doesn't get called when action is clicked or tel scheme see my updated question